# ASP.Net error "Unable to start program http://localhost:123/myapp/"

Tags: asp.net, internet-explorer

Well since i installed IE 8 i get this error so i cant debug my asp.net page :(

"Unable to start program http://localhost:123/myapp/"
Could not find the element(or some thing like that translated from swe)

What must i do to get rid of this error? and IE more or less hangs after this, the window does respond but it only loads half of it components...

Edit: Is there any way to set what browser to use when debugging befor i installed IE8 i normaly used opera and it worked like i wanted it to...

Comment: What makes you think this is a "Bug" in ASP.NET, rather than a configuration error with your system/installation ?

Comment: well ok then its a configuration error but i havent done any configuration on my own so how do i fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think you IE 8 is not properly installed try setting other browser as default browser.
if you don't get this error then it means you have to re install ie 8 again

Comment: Please try the other answer before you go to this extreme. It's actually just a simple IE8 setting change.

Answer (score 1):

Hi all these type of user i had resolved this error so u also must try it as follow below steps:

This is one of the various errors that appear when you are debugging and may haunt you until you do the following fix:-

1. In the Internet Explorer, "Tools" Menu, select "Internet Options".
2. Switch to "Security" Tab.
3. Click on "Internet" (The Globe Icon. Its actually the default selected).
4. Click on "Custom Level" in the bottom.
5. Scroll down to find the "User Authentication" section.
6. Select "Automatic logon with current username and password".
   OR Anonymous logon.
7. Click "Ok" twice to exit.

Restart IE. (You don't need to reinstall your browser.)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are facing [this known issue](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/ViewFeedback.aspx?FeedbackID=387883)? This [blog post](http://blogs.iis.net/brian-murphy-booth/archive/2008/06/03/visual-studio-2008-unable-to-debug-asp-net-app-on-iis-7-0.aspx) also describes a workaround.